# Redirect with RewriteRule apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to make an internal redirect with this result:

My old link is like: http://www.example.com/en/some-other-things
My new link should be: http://www.example.com/some-other-things

Basically I want to 'remove' the /en/ and get all the rest of the url in the new url. I've tried this rules in the .htaccess without success:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^/en/(.+)" "/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make leading slash optional so that rule works both in Apache config as well in .htaccess files. Use `.*` instead of `.+` to ensure you match `example.com/en/` as well. Also there is no need to quote the pattern or target.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm ;). You've saved my day.